# No signal after PC upgrade

Tags: upgrade, vga

I just plugged in a new MSI R7 250 VGA and the mobo and RAM. The computer is running, but I get no signal from the monitor. I tried putting in the VGA again, but I still get no signal.

Specs:

- mobo: Asrock AM3+ 970 EXTREME3
- CPU: AMD AM3+ FX-6300 14MB (3.5Ghz)
- GPU: MSI R7 250 OC 2GD3 2048MB

The monitor works fine. I tested it out with another VGA. What else can I check?

Comment: Have you tried to boot into safe mode to download and install the drivers for the new video card, then reboot?

Answer (score 0):

Do these steps (order does not matter)

- Make sure your VGA cable is plugged into the Graphics Card
- Make sure your Graphics card is plugged in correctly
- Screw in your VGA cable to monitor and GPU
- Try Swapping RAM configurations (This works, really do this)
- Test with a different cable, monitor and port

Comment: Tried all and none work.

Answer (score 0):

Check your BIOS settings to see which display output is enabled. If your mobo has a built-in display output or a second graphics card, it may have switched to using that.

Make sure the PCI slot where you installed your new graphics card is turned on in your BIOS settings.